# Issues with Torch

Tags: macos, terminal, torch

Last login: Fri Mar 23 14:55:26 on ttys000
-bash: /Users/Bhaskar/torch/install/bin/torch-activate: No such file or directory

I get this message whenever I open my Terminal. I am not sure what I have to do to make this go away!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this command in my ~/.profile and ~/.bash_rc scripts. Deleting those lines (and re-installing the teamocil gem) made this error go away. Hope this helps

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer. I couldn't manage to delete those lines. :(